# Largest $k$ for which $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos nx}{2^n}$ is in $C^k$ with respect to $x$

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

I was asked to find the largest number $k$ for which the real function $$x \mapsto \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos nx}{2^n}$$
is in the differentiability class $C^k$.

I can't seem to think of a way to approach this question..any help will be gladly accepted!

Comment: There is a close relation between decay rate of fourier coefficients and the regularity class of the limit function. Here you have exponential decay (faster decay than each polynomial) and thus that series defines a smooth function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The series is uniformly convergent on $\mathbb R$ (by the M-test), so the function

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos nx}{2^n} $$

is differentiable on $\mathbb R$ and

$$f'(x) =- \sum_{n=1}^\infty n\frac{\sin nx}{2^n} $$

You can apply the same trick to $f'$ and conclude that $f'$ is differentiable. By induction you can work out that $f^{(k)}$ is differentiable for all $k$ and so $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! Isn't induction used to prove a finite numbers problem?
Also, what happens if i change the cos(nx) to cos((2^n)x)? :)

Comment: Induction is used to prove tha a property holds for _all_ natural numbers, which is what you want in order to show that $f \in C^\infty$. If you have $\cos(2^n x)$, $f$ is still a continuous function, but the series of the derivatives fails to converge for all $x \neq 0$...

Answer (score 4):

While this is probably not the intended method to solve this problem, you can actually sum this series up explicitly via a quick detour into the complex plane and examine the properties of the resulting function.  By Euler's identity, we have
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos nx}{2^n} = \Re \left[ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{inx}}{2^n} \right] = \Re \left[ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{e^{ix}}{2} \right)^n \right].
$$
The sum in square brackets is a geometric series;  and since the magnitude of the ratio of successive terms is
$$
\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| = \left|\frac{e^{ix}}{2}\right| = \frac{1}{2} < 1
$$
for all values of $x$, the series converges to
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{e^{ix}}{2} \right)^n = \frac{\frac{1}{2} e^{ix}}{1 - \frac{1}{2} e^{ix}}.
$$
Taking the real part of this, we conclude that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos nx}{2^n} = \frac{ \frac{1}{2} \cos x - \frac{1}{4}}{\frac{5}{4} - \cos x}
$$
This is obviously a $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ function, since it is the quotient of two $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ functions (and the denominator never vanishes.)

Answer (score 3):

A function $f$ is of differentiability  class $C^k$ if the derivatives $f', f'', ...,f^{(k)}$ exist and are continuous, so that is what you would like to check.

By a well known theorem (7.17 in Baby Rudin), if $$f(x) = \lim_{N \to \infty} \underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\cos{nx}}{2^n}}_{f_N(x)}$$ is differentiabile for each $N$, and if the limit exists for some $x$ value, and if $\{f_N'\}$ converges uniformly (for all $x$ values), then
$$f'(x) = \lim_{N \to \infty} F_N'(x).$$

After checking that the "if" conditions are true, you can compute 
$$f'(x) = \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{d}{dx} \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\cos{nx}}{2^n} = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n = 1}^{N} \frac{d}{dx} \frac{\cos{nx}}{2^n} = \lim_{N \to \infty} -\sum_{n = 1}^N \frac{n \sin{nx}}{2^n}.$$ 
Then you can check the "if" conditions again and then compute $f''(x)$, and check again and compute $f'''(x)$, all the way up to $f^{(k)}(x)$ by induction. You can then argue that $f^{(k)}(x)$ is continuous since each term if the sequence is continuous (if $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of continuous functions and $f_n \to f$ uniformly, then $f$ is continuous by Theorem 7.12 in Baby Rudin).

This is just my initial thoughts, hopefully it gives you something to work with.

Answer (score 2):

Let $$ f: \mathbb{D} \to\mathbb{C} $$ $$f(z) =\sum_{n>0} z ^n $$ and $$f: \mathbb{D} \to\mathbb{C}$$ $$g(z)=\frac{e^{ix}}{2} $$
then $$\sum_{n>0} \frac{\cos nx}{2^n} =\mbox{Re} {(f\circ g)(x)}$$
hence it is harmonic and thus $C^{\infty} $ class.

Comment: Hello! thank you very much for your answer but I did not study a term that's called harmonic (yet?) :(